# Gain access to the original `this` passed to a constructor before the constructor returns a different instance object

Tags: javascript, new-operator

I have to use a certain third-party library that works in the following way:

```js
const Thing = function () {
  if (!new.target) return new Thing() // Note: This previously wasn't there

  const privateData = this

  privateData.somethingPrivate = 123

  return {
    someFunction () {
      return privateData.somethingPrivate
    }
  }
}

module.exports = Thing
```

As you can see, it wants to be called with `new`, but it then uses the auto-created `this` instance object as a container for private data and instead returns a fresh object (that doesn't even have the right prototype) with public functions.

So, we can do this...

```js
const Thing = require('thing')

const thing = new Thing()

console.log(thing.someFunction()) // 123
```

...but we cannot do this:

```js
thing.somethingPrivate = 456 // Does nothing
```

For reasons I can't explain here right now, I have to be able to access private data like `somethingPrivate` from the outside. Also, forking the library is not an option at the moment. I know this sounds like an XY problem but trust me, it's not. I know I'm trying to do something that I'm not "supposed" to do (and I know I have to be careful with library updates) but I need a creative solution here. (And no, this is not for nefarious purposes.)

Now, what would be needed to access `somethingPrivate` is gaining access to the original `this` that the constructor `Thing` is getting called with. This object is created by JS itself through the `new` operator. (Normally, this object is also returned from the `new` operator, unless the constructor returns another object, which is what happens here.)

Originally, the line `if (!new.target) return new Thing()` didn't exist in the library. I had a solution that looked like this (doing something similar to what the `new` operator would be doing, but keeping a reference to the original `this`):

```js
const Thing = require('thing')

const thingPrivateData = Object.create(Thing) // Manually create instance, keep reference
const thing = Thing.call(privateData) // Call constructor on the instance
thing._private = thingPrivateData // Assign original "private" instance to a public property
```

Afterwards, I was able to access `somethingPrivate` like this:

```js
thing._private.privateData = 456 // Works!
```

However, in a recent update, the library added the line `if (!new.target) return new Thing()` which rendered my solution useless, because my manual invokation of `Thing` would not set the `new.target` value and the library would then call itself again with `new`, so the `this` that I passed in manually would not be used and instead a new instance object would be created.

I researched into `Reflect.construct` and hoped I could do something like this:

```js
const Thing = require('thing')

const thing = Reflect.construct(function () {
  const obj = Thing.call(this) // This doesn't work because yet again new.target is unset
  obj._private = this
  return obj
}, [], Thing)
```

But of course it doesn't work because even though `new.target` is set in *my* (anonymous) function, it is unset again when I call into `Thing`, because that call again is without `new`/`Reflect.construct`.

Am I out of luck or **is there some sort of creative way to get access to that original instance passed to as `this` to the constructor**, and/or to **set `new.target` in an invocation while *also* passing a custom `this`** (and not a prototype from which one is auto-created)?

Comment: Maybe using a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).  If you scoll down in the page a little, there is an example for extending a constructor.

Comment: This wouldn't work though because the proxy trap runs before the object is instantiated, and as I mentioned the `Reflect.construct` method takes a constructor and not an already-instantiated object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution for my specific problem but it feels even dirtier than I want. I would still be interested in other answers!

My current solution is as follows:

```js
let privateData
const Hook = function () {} // Without a function we get "#<Object> is not a constructor"
Hook.prototype = new Proxy(Thing.prototype, {
  set: function (target, prop, value) {
    privateData = target
    return Reflect.set(target, prop, value)
  }
})

const thing = Reflect.construct(Thing, [], Hook)
thing._private = privateData
```

Afterwards, `thing._private.somethingPrivate` works as it did with my previous solution.

This works because apparently the proxy trap I set on the prototype is carried over to the object instance somehow (although I'm not 100% sure why it works this way), and when the constructor writes to the private data fields, it triggers my trap and I can save a reference to the internal object.

<sub>Note that this only works because the constructor in this library is already writing to the `this` object. If it would not (and only methods would do that when called later) then I would need a more complicated solution where the proxy would actually trap both `get` and `set` and redirect all property reads/writes to another object instead. This way we would not have access to the actual `this` but we would have something almost equivalent - we would control what data the library reads from the object and we would see what it writes.</sub>